# Problem using recursion trying to make a descending list in c

Tags: c, recursion, printf, function-definition

I have a problem with recursion, I am trying to get the user to enter a number and print the numbers down to number 1 on the screen.

(I would appreciate if you explain to me how the solution works since I am learning and it is quite complicated for me.)

e.g., the user enters number 5 and I want it to show:
5.
4.
3.
2.
1.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int list(int n);

int main(){
    int i,number;
    
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    
    for(i = number;i > 0;i--){
        printf("%i.\n", list(i));
    }
    
    return 0;   
}


int list(int n){
    if(n == 1||n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return list(n); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Fyi, `return list(n)` How do you *ever* expect the recursed call to behave any differently than the current call when you're passing precisely the same argument value that you have in the first place? And fyi, the point of this exercise is *recursion*. I.e. that for loop shouldn't be in this code, and the output should be in the recursive function itself.

Comment: None of this makes any sense.  You want `list(n)` to return `n`, right?  How does it makes sense to use recursion to obtain a value you already have?  In any case, if you call `list(n)` from within `list(n)`, you're going to just recurse until you exhaust your stack space.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a recursion then you don't need a for loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void list(int n);

int main() {
  int i, number;

  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", & number);
  /*   for(i = number;i > 0;i--){
         printf("%i.\n", list(i));
     }*/
  list(number);
  return 0;
}
//Prints the number and calls its 
//preceding number untill 1 is encountered
void list(int n) {
  if (n == 1 || n == 0) {
    printf("1.");
  } else {
    printf("%d. ", n);
    //return list(n) never returns previous number 
    return list(n - 1); //returns (n-1)'s previous numbers
  }
}
```

If you just want the same using a for loop, you can go for the following code.

```
for(int i = number ; i>0 ; i--)
  printf("%d. ",i);
```

Answer (score 1):

This function

```
int list(int n){
    if(n == 1||n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return list(n); 
    }
}
```

does not make sense and can produce stack overflow due to infinite recursive calls of itself when n is not equal to 0 and 1.

Even if you will change it the following way

```
int list(int n){
    if(n == 1||n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return list(n - 1);    // <=== 
    }
}
```

nevertheless the function again can produce stack overflow if the parameter `n` has a negative value. And moreover for a non-negative value the function will always return `1` and output nothing.

So the function as is does not make any sense.

Pay attention to that the parameter of the function should have the type `unsigned int` because the function is not designed to deal with negative numbers. And the return type of the function `int` also does not make a great sense.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be declared and defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void list( unsigned int n )
{
    n == 0 ? ( ( void )putchar( '\n' ) ) : ( printf( "%d.", n ), list( n - 1 ) );
}

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );
        
        unsigned int n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        list( n );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

5.4.3.2.1.

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

4.3.2.1.

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

3.2.1.

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

2.1.

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

1.

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Enjoy!:)

Answer (score -1):

As the the previous answer points out, you don't need recursion for this, but can be done that way if you want. This version merges all results to a single string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char* list(int n);

int main(){
    int i,number=5;
    
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    
    printf("%s", list(number));  // full list 5 4 3 2 1

    return 0;   
}


const char* list(int n){
    if(n == 1||n == 0){
        return "1";
    }
    else {
        char *str = (char*)malloc(20);
        sprintf(str, "%d %s", n, list(n-1)); // this value plus remaining values
        return str; 
    }
}
```

Output

```
5 4 3 2 1
```